# OpenCart set multiple weight based shipping methods

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Is there a way to setup few custom shipping methods ?
For example:

Shipping A (specific countries): kg:price
1:29.90, 2:35.90, 3:49

Shipping B (specific countries): kg:price
1:35.80, 2:44, 3:51

Shipping C (specific countries): kg:price
1:39.90, 2:48.50, 3:54.90

Comment: check this link it might help you http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/how-to-use-opencart-weight-based-shipping-for-multiple-flat-rates/

Comment: Awesome man, thanks!